# Generics and Events - is there any way to do this?

Tags: c#, events, generics

After all isssues  I ran into recently with concurrency of subscribing/ unsubscribing and notifying I tried to put i tall in a generic class and use it.

Alas I fail to find a way since this is not allowed:

```
 public class LCLMulticastEvent<T> where T: System.MulticastDelegate
    {
        private event T internalEvent;

        private object lockObject = new object();

        public event T OnEvent
        { 
           add 
           { 
             lock( lockObject )
             {
                internalEvent += value; 
             }
           }

           remove 
           { 
               lock( lockObject )
               {
                  internalEvent += value; 
               }
            }
        }
        public void notify( params object[] args)
        { 
           if( internalEvent != null )
           {
               lock( lockObject )
               {
                   foreach( T invokee in internalEvent.GetInvocationList() )
                   {
                           invokee.DynamicInvoke( args );
                   }
               }
           }
        }

    }
```

The compiler refuses to accept `System.MulticastDelegate` , saying it is a special class...

Is there any way to do it?

Edit: I tried to be too brief in my first exmplanations. 
What I wanted to to is implement a kind of event-wrapper that is thread-safe.
@Thomas: DynamicInvoke should have been the solution...

TIA

Mario

Comment: What issues are you having? Simply making an `event` to subscribe to is all you need...

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do... could you give more details?

Comment: And anyway, how would you raise the event? You need to know the signature of the delegate...

Comment: @Thomas: See my post, DynamicInvoke came to my rescue

Comment: @Tejs: again subscribing/ unsubscribing and notifing is not thread safe (synchronized)

Comment: @Mario The Spoon, just keep in mind that DynamicInvoke is *very* slow...

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear to me what you are trying to achieve here, but maybe this helps: you can make the class generic in the `EventArgs` type instead of MultiCastDelegate

```
public class LCLMulticastEvent<TEventArgs> where TEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private event EventHandler<TEventArgs> internalEvent;

    private object lockObject = new object();

    public event EventHandler<TEventArgs> OnEvent
    { 
        add { internalEvent += value; }
        remove { internalEvent -= value; }
    } 
}
```